# DateTime.ParseExact does not work as expected

Tags: c#

How should the input string format be in `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Just trying this out and I kept getting exception error:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact("3/15/2019 06:30:23 PM", "M /d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
//this works though..
string test = "3/15/2019 06:30:23 PM";
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "M /d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Aren't both the lines the same? How come one throws error?

Comment: The second bit of code fails for me too. They both fail because of the extra space.

Comment: If you say so, what's the error thrown?

Comment: @Enigmativity - thank you, that worked. I tried another way,

Comment: @Enigmativity, I tried another way and it fails. The earlier one worked after deleting the extra space 'string er = "PM";
            DateTime test1 = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("3/15/2019 06:30:23 {0}",er));
            DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(test1.ToString(), "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);   and it fails, it throws the system.format exception. Am I missing something'

Comment: @Cally This is the ugliest way to do! You are doing the same thing twice. See my answer

Comment: Got it, I was just trying to use the formatting, but I will go with the above one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> aren't both the lines the same? How come one throws error?

I see both lines throwing error saying `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` due to the space after `M` in `"M /d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` in both lines.

Remove the space after the `M` from `"M /d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` and then write as follows:

```
string test = "3/15/2019 06:30:23 PM";
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```